# C++ output information to a new window

Tags: c++, window, output

So I want to run a code and output the information to a new window to have a clean window with only the information I want.
I am using Angstrom linux system and I have a code that if I run, there are too many information showing on the terminal. 
Is there a way for me to create a new window or terminal with the information I want?
Thank you

Comment: Either you write a logfile from inside your program and monitor it by follow mode of tail or less. Or do this , processname >> log.txt to get your terminal output to a file and view it later.

Comment: Is there a way to constantly monitor the changes to the log? I am trying to show changing informations on a clean window

Comment: the follow mode of less or tail is the one you need to monitor. It will auto-scroll the log as it gets printed. http://www.oreillynet.com/linux/cmd/cmd.csp?path=l/less

see the 'F' option

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround you can do. just print the info you need to a file (for instance log.txt) and then open a new terminal window and use:

```
tail -f log.txt
```

this will display the info you need on the terminal window as it comes up